# IA32 Assembly Number Mystery

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86

I'm having trouble with a programming homework problem in assembly. I have to enter 2 numbers into the console to "diffuse a bomb". The only clue I have to figure out what these two numbers are is by reading the assembly code. Within the assembly code, there are 3 criteria that the numbers (let's call them a and b) must satisfy:

1. `a + b = 3997`
2. `((2 * a) & a) & ((2 * a) & a) = 0`
3. `(a ^ b) & (a ^ b) <= 0`

For clarification, `*` is the multiplication operator, `+` is the addition operator, `&` is the bitwise AND operator, and `^` is the bitwise XOR operator

It's got me stumped. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm hoping that `+` is addition and `*` is multiplication, but sometimes different meanings are applied to symbols like `^` and `&` - can you clarify exactly what operations you mean each of your operators to be please?

Comment: Certainly: `*` signifies multiplication, `^` signifies a bitwise XOR operation, `&` signifies a bitwise AND operation

Comment: Probably worth hitting the `edit` button at the bottom of your question and adding this information, rather than doing it in the comments

Comment: Then can't number 2 be simplified to just `((2 * a) & a) = 0` - unless I'm mistaken, both sides of the outer `&` are identical, and the only value that, when `&`ed with itself produces `0` is `0`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - I was just writing it the way it's performed in assembly to make sure any dumb oversights on my part weren't missed. Is it just me or does number 3 stipulate that `a = b`?

Comment: This is easy if you throw it into a [solver](http://goo.gl/wcEXoE). There are 5702133 solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From point #2: `x & x = 0` if and only if `x = 0`, so `(2 * a) & a = 0`. Since multiplying by 2 is a single bit shift, we can see that this is true for any number that doesn't have two set bits next to each other.

From point #3: `x & x <= 0` if and only if `x <= 0`, so that means `a ^ b <= 0`. If `a ^ b = 0` that would mean `a = b` but point #1 doesn't allow that because `3997` is odd. Thus, `a ^ b < 0` which means `a` and `b` differ in the sign bit, that is one is positive or zero, the other is negative.

These leave us some freedom of choice. For point #2 we can simply pick a power of 2 that is greater than `3997`, then calculate the other number by subtracting from `3997`. For example, `a = 4096`, `b = -99`:

1. 4096 + (-99) = 3997
2. ((2 * 4096) & 4096) & ((2 * 4096) & 4096) = 0
3. (4096 ^ -99) & (4096 ^ -99) = -4195

There are many other solutions.

Comment: I"m wondering if the original post is using <= to mean not equal (possibly it meant <> which is an alternative syntax for not equal in some languages) instead of less than or equal.

Comment: Forgot to say it at the time (vicious deadlines) but thanks very much. This answer totally worked.